# How to tell if using EF5

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Am taking a Silverlight / WCF RIA Service project from EF4 to EF5.  Target is .NET4.5

Here is a spike - am using a DB First approach.  ie create edmx, then use the Domain Services Classes Wizard

[image]

So looking good so far as have

- EntityFramework (5.0.0.0)
- Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework (4.0.0.0) DbDomainService in here
- System.Data.Entity (4.0.0.0)

as opposed to old way of:

- EntityFramework (5.0.0.0)
- System.Data.Entity (4.0.0.0)
- System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework (4.0.0.0) LinqToEntitiesDomainService in here

[image]

then have put a simple UI on to access the 2 table db and it worked
[image]

**Problem:**  This web.config isn't what I expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel">
      <section name="domainServices" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
   <!-- profile stuff commented out-->
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-BusinessApplication5.Web-20130603151851;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TestDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=TestDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I was expecting to have to put in:

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Got these bits of config from the following.  Perhaps they are all codefirst specific.
https://github.com/jeffhandley/riabooks

http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2012/12/10/RIA-Services-NuGet-Package-Updates-ndash-Including-Support-for-EntityFramework.aspx

http://mcasamento.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/entity-framework-5-code-first-and-wcf.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RIA Services dll is compiled against EF 4, not EF5, so the binding Redirect is used to make everything work. If/when RIA Services is open sourced there will be a new release of RiaServices.EntityFramework that will be compiled against EF 5 and EF 6. One of the benefits of open source will be the ability to put out as many NuGet packages as I want to support all combinations.

Comment: Thanks Colin - Wrote up my notes here http://www.programgood.net/2013/06/04/EF5AndRIAServicesHowToReallyDoIt.aspx